# How to beat level 24 in Chessformer?

Tags: logical-deduction, chess

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3Xsc.png) is Level 24 in [Chessformer](https://armorgames.com/chessformer-game/19096):

[image]

This is pretty easy to do at first, as long as you don't click the restart button (which I did by complete accident when I had some good progress on this level):

1. Look at that key. That is obviously only accessible by Knight, so we first get two Bishops onto the platform right next to the key like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4pT6.png):

[image]

2. Then, [put a Knight on the two Bishops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3RcY.png):

[image]

3. Then notice that the red king is only killable by a king. It's just barely too short for a knight, and too short for a bishop. So, how do we get the king over there? We [create a tower of pieces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S14m.png):

[image]

4. Then, we get the rook almost all of the way to the right so we can use the knight to [turn off the purple block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgeCp.png):

[image]

Now here's where I've been stuck. I now need to get the king stacked on three pieces so that it can go and kill the opponent king, but no matter what I do, I'm unable to get enough pieces on the right side so that the king can tower up and reach the opponent king.

So my question is: How do I beat this level? This is the only one I haven't beaten and I really want to be able to beat it, as I have been stuck on this level for around 3 weeks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't actually played this game so might be misunderstanding, but it looks as if the following works, starting from your final position:

1. Get the RH knight back over to the left via h1.
2. Now you can get *both* bishops onto the platform via a4, and hence across to the right side.
3. Then move the knights back to the right via f2 and h1.
4. Now you have five pieces plus the king on the right and you can get a configuration with the king on l3 and other pieces on l1, l2, m1, m2, m3.

Comment: Yes, that seems to help. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @CrSb0001 just curious, which parts were the most enlightening for you? The moving of knight back to the left to assist? The paths via a4 for bishops to go to the right?

Comment: I'm not CrSb0001, but I know what the last bit I figured out was: the fact that you can move the RH knight back to the LH side. It's not that it's conceptually difficult, it's just easy to forget that it's still available on the left after you've moved it to the right to do something there.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan that's possible yep. I was just wondering since the purple button isn't really required to be pressed until the king has passed to the upper right side. But in the question OP seems to head that first before moving the king, so probably you're right.